# how to name the result of the list of a list in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following list of a list.

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
ss <- c(4,5,6)
S <- list(s,ss)
h <- c(4,8,7)
hh <- c(0,3,4)
H <- list(h,hh)
HH <- list(S,H)
```

I would like to name the result of the list as follows:

```
$First_model
$Res_1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$Res_2[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6


$Second_model
$Res_1[[1]]
[1] 4 8 7

$Res_2[[2]]
[1] 0 3 4
```

I tried the following, but it is not what I expected.

```
names1 <- c("First","Second")
# And second you paste them to your list
names(HH) <- paste0(names1,"_result",  sep = "")
```

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the way the list is printed. Your expected output is not valid, since `$First_model` should also be the start of the second line. It's the `[[1]]` you want to replace by `$Res_1`. You can do that by, for example, `names(HH$First) <- c("Res_1", "Res_2")`

Comment: A (maybe) nicer way to show the list is by `str(HH)`

Comment: @Bas Many thanks for your amazing help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following -

```
names1 <- c("First","Second")

lapply(setNames(HH, paste0(names1, '_Model')), function(x) 
  setNames(x, paste0('Res_', seq_along(x))))

#$First_Model
#$First_Model$Res_1
#[1] 1 2 3

#$First_Model$Res_2
#[1] 4 5 6


#$Second_Model
#$Second_Model$Res_1
#[1] 4 8 7

#$Second_Model$Res_2
#[1] 0 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(purrr)
s <- c(1,2,3)
ss <- c(4,5,6)
S <- list(s,ss)
h <- c(4,8,7)
hh <- c(0,3,4)
H <- list(h,hh)
HH <- list(S,H)

names1 <- c("First","Second")
set_names(HH, names1) %>% map(~set_names(..1, c('Res_1', 'Res_2')))
#> $First
#> $First$Res_1
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $First$Res_2
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> 
#> $Second
#> $Second$Res_1
#> [1] 4 8 7
#> 
#> $Second$Res_2
#> [1] 0 3 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>